# Uninstall an extension from Magento 1.9 and I can't add products to my site

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I was using a extension "Multi Vendor Marketplace Add-On" from my website with magento 1.9 Now I can't install or edit existing products, The error I am having is

```
There has been an error processing your request
Source model "marketplace/source_option" not found for attribute "seller_id"

Trace:
#0 
 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(390): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "m...')
#1 
/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2
/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
#3 
/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 
/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(922): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
 #5 
  /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
```

Things I have did so far to resolve this error
Disable the compiler
Reindex all componets
Clear cache
Contact Developers that but they are not replying

Issue as far I understands the uninstall extensions was having relational table to product tables, now why still relationship after uninstall or how can we remove this relationship?
Any idea that can leads me to solve this will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this things.

1. Open magento database.
2. Open table name is `"eav_attribute"`
3. Serch into column `"attribute_code"` where you find entry `"seller_id"`
4. remove that record from table.

Now try what every you like.